# Colocar icono en la pestaña

Tags: html, html5

Estoy intentando colocar un icono en mi pestaña, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo favicon.ico está en la misma carpeta que el archivo donde coloco este código:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Pero no hace nada, me deja el icono del xamp...

Comment: prueba borrar el cache

Comment: Y lo he probado.

Comment: De que tamaño es tu imagen? Es un archivo transformado a .ICO o renombrado a .ICO? Deberías poder verlo sin problemas, a menos que el archivo .ICO esté corrupto. Puedes usar el explorador de recursos de Chrome (F12 o CTRL+J) para ver los archivos que el explorador levanta. Tu archivo favicon.ico debería estar en el listado de recursos levantados. Si esto no sucede, revisa la existencia del archivo y la referencia.

Comment: me parece un problema de chaché intenta favicon.ico?v=2 Si eso soluciona el problema si es la caché

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece que la url del href esta mal, prueba esto:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Igualmente siempre borrar la cache de la pagina para que se actualice el cambio

Comment: No funciona de esta manera tampoco.

Comment: Ve al código fuente de la pagina y busca la url dale clic y si no te carga la img nueva es porque tienes que borrar la cache

Answer (score 7):

Si ves el ícono de XAMPP es por que sigue levantando ese ícono. Busca dentro de la carpeta de tu servidor XAMPP este ícono y elimínalo. Reemplazalo con tu ícono y debería funcionar.

Si al modificar el archivo **favicon.ico** sigues viendo el ícono de XAMPP, deberás refrescar la cache de tu navegador para que vuelva a cargar todos los recursos. Un refresco de página mas caché lo consigues con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Windows/Linux) o <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Mac)

Vale aclarar que la dirección del ícono aunque esta bien escrita es siempre relativa al root del servidor, no necesariamente el mismo nivel donde tienes tu archivo HTML.

Comment: Pero entonces cuando yo suba mi página a un servidor online, se verá la imagen que tengo en mi directorio? Es decir, la que yo le suba y tenga en mi direccion de /favicon ?

Comment: Cuando subas a un server, no vas a tener que pisar el favicon por que seguramente no tengas ninguno creado. Asi que sí, deberia ser transparente, deberia verse sin problemas

Answer (score 1):

yo acabo de hacerlo y me ha funcionado de la siguiente manera:

Eso sí, previamente he tenido que transformar mi imagen jpg a favicon.ico, lo he hecho con el editor GIMP 2.10.22, a un tamaño cuadrado de max 31x31, primero he exportado la imagen como jpg y posteriormente, en el propio Visual Studio la he renombrado a favicon.ico

Otra cosa, Este código tiene que ir en la parte del hea, la etiqueta de link no está dentro de title.

A ver así! :)

Answer (score 0):

solo agregas un link en el encabezado de la pagina, con rel =icon y la url completa del icono. Aqui ejemplo con el icono de es.stackoverflow.com:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Icono en el navegador</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=7739871010e6
">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test de Icono en el tab de navegador</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que yo he usado para poner una imagen en la pestaña del navegador es:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png">
```

en mi caso, tenia la imagen en una carpeta llamada imágenes, ojo; a muchos no les funciona, no porque el código no sirva si no por los posibles errores que podamos tener en la estructura del código.

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia esta respuesta a los intentos del autor de la pregunta? O ¿cuál es la diferencia respecto a las demás respuestas brindadas?

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funcionó así -->

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tulogo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

PD: La imagen deberá estar en la misma carpeta. O el href deberás especificar, si está dentro de una carpeta será `href="tucarpeta/tulogo.ico"`
Y si el archivo está antes, osea que debes retroceder, seria así -->

```
href="../tucarpeta/tulogo.ico"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<link rel="icon"  type="image/png" href="nombre de la imagen .tipo de archico ejemplo png">
```

Enlace en comentarios

Y ya.
 Debes de ponerlo en el encabezado, la imagen debe de estar en la misma carpeta de la página.

Comment: <link rel="ICON"  type="iMAGEN/PNG" href="NOMBRE DE LA IMAGEN .TIPO DE ARCHICO EJEMPLO PNG">

Comment: Edwin, bienvenido a SOes. Porfavor has el [tour] cuanto antes. Porfavor, no escribas en mayusculas, se entiende como si estas gritando. Toda publicacion puede ser editada para incluir mas informacion. Considera [edit] apropiadamente la tuya. Recuerda leer el articulo [mcve] para mejorar tu respuesta y porfavor, vigila tu ortografia.